# Do Group by on one column and then split the group on categorical column's 2 specific values and the finally get the First and last records

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, analysis

After group by on Id column, I would like to split the group again on a categorical column's 2 specific values and the the get the first and last rows as the final output to find the percent drop.
To make the problem easier, I can only filter the dataframe to contain 2 specific categorical value rows. Below is the sample dataframe after filter as explained above to make this easier.
[image]

The EncDate in the image above for sample data is different than the code written below.Sample Data code :

```
import pandas as pd


rng = pd.date_range('2015-02-24', periods=20, freq='M')

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Id': [ '21','21','21','29','29','29','29','29','29','29','29','29','29','67','67','67','67','67','67','67'],
    'Score': [21,21,21,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,67,67,67,67,67,67,67],
    'Dx': ['F11','F11','F11','F72','F72','F72','F72','F72','F72','F72','F72','F72','F72','F72','F72','F72','F72','F72','F72','F72'],
    'EncDate' :  rng, 
    'Treatment': ['Active','Active','Inactive','Inactive','Active','Active','Active','Active ','Inactive','Active','Active','Active ','Inactive','Active','Active','Active ','Inactive','Active','Active','Inactive'],
    'ProviderName': ["Doe, Kim","Doe, Kim","Doe, Kim","Lee, Mei","Lee, Mei","Lee, Mei","Lee, Mei","Lee, Mei","Lee, Mei","Lee, Mei","Lee, Mei","Lee, Mei","Lee, Mei","Shah, Neha","Shah, Neha","Shah, Neha","Shah, Neha","Shah, Neha","Shah, Neha","Shah, Neha"]
})
```

I want to group by Id column and then Treatment such a way that a Treatment group should start from Active to Inactive chronologically EncDate. For e.g: For Id 29, the treatment had been started 2 times. Treatment starts when the value is "Active" and that same Treatment ends when a doctor documents "Inactive". For Id 29 and 67, treatment started and ended Twice. I need to mark first active treatment as First and the subsequent Inactive as Last and then Find the Score drop between them.

Comment: And where is your attempt to solve the problem?

Comment: can you please provide your starting df in a way that it can by copied and pasted?

Comment: Let me add python code to create a dataframe of data from image above. I will be editing the post with python clode in an hour.

Comment: df = df.sort_values(['Id', 'EncDate'])       idxForNoEoa = df.groupby('Id').agg(['first', 'last']).stack()     This is how I tried to solve which does not work when a patient which is Id column comes twice for the course of treatment: for Id 29 and 67

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
g = df.groupby('Id')['Treatment'].transform(lambda x: (x.eq('Inactive').shift().fillna(0))).cumsum()

ndf = df.loc[g.groupby([df['Id'],g]).transform('count').ne(1)].groupby(['Id',g],as_index=False).nth([0,-1])

ndf.assign(PercentDrop = ndf.groupby(['Id',g])['Score'].pct_change())
```

Output:

```
    Id  Score   Dx    EncDate Treatment ProviderName  PercentDrop
0   21     22  F11 2015-02-28    Active     Doe, Kim          NaN
2   21      9  F11 2015-04-30  Inactive     Doe, Kim    -0.307692
4   29     25  F72 2015-06-30    Active     Lee, Mei          NaN
8   29      8  F72 2015-10-31  Inactive     Lee, Mei    -0.272727
9   29     28  F72 2015-11-30    Active     Lee, Mei          NaN
12  29      8  F72 2016-02-29  Inactive     Lee, Mei    -0.466667
13  67     26  F72 2016-03-31    Active   Shah, Neha          NaN
16  67     10  F72 2016-06-30  Inactive   Shah, Neha    -0.375000
17  67     24  F72 2016-07-31    Active   Shah, Neha          NaN
19  67      7  F72 2016-09-30  Inactive   Shah, Neha    -0.533333
```